# Unity problem with instantiated objects when destroyed

Tags: unity, c#, game-loop, visual-studio, shooter

So this is my problem, I have a square that when destroyed spawn 4 smaller squares when shooting on it, but when I shoot one of the 4 smaller squares sometimes a different square that are not even close gets destroyed.

The problem is worse when it has multiple smaller squares because just shooting one of the squares continuously make the other ones get destroy except the one i'm shooting

Comment: To help you it would be the easiest if you post your code as well (the one that spawns your smaller blocks and the one responsible for destruction)

Comment: Are you using RayCast for doing this? Also, post your code :)